# Fetching current period on the basis of given date using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose I have a sql table with the following structure

```sql
create table periods(
id INT(6)  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255),
start_date date,
end_date date);
```

and it has the following records in it.

```
id  name     start_date end_date

1   Period1  21.07.19   30.07.19
2   Period2  01.08.19   10.08.19
3   Period3  11.08.19   20.08.19
4   Period4  21.08.19   30.08.19
5   Period5  01.09.19   10.09.19
6   Period6  11.09.19   20.09.19
7   Period7  21.09.19   30.09.19
8   Period8  01.10.19   10.10.19
9   Period9  11.10.19   20.10.19
10  Period10 21.10.19   30.10.19
```

Now suppose I want to find the current period on the basis of a given date. That is if today is `2019-08-02 (YYYY-MM-DD)` then the current period should be `Period2` as it lies between the `start date` and `end date` of Period 2, therefore I should get back the row with `Period2`. How can I achieve this using `MYSQL` query?

Looking for advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `where`:

```
select p.*
from periods p
where curdate() >= p.start_date and
      curdate() <= p.end_date;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Was that simple, so silly of me...sometimes your brain just doesn't work. Thanks. :)